# How do I use FileZilla to transfer only the latest version of a file when copying from OpenVMS?

Tags: ftp, filezilla, openvms

I'm using FileZilla to copy a directory from an OpenVMS system to my local PC. When the files arrive, all versions of each file are copied and the names have the version number appended to them as an extension.

This isn't quite what we want; is there any way to get FileZilla to copy only the latest version and not add the version number to the file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was raised in the FileZilla forums, see [this topic](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5725&start=0).

> In version 2 there was a checkbox on the File Transfer Setting page: "Display all file revisions on VMS servers".
>   When you unchecked that, only one file revision would be shown without the trailing semicolon and version number and those would not be included in the local file name either.

You can find download links of version 2 [here](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7089).

Answer (score 1):

Copied from
http://www.softpedia.com/progChangelog/FileZilla-Changelog-5771.html

New features:
Added experimental setting to strip file revision upon download from VMS servers. Set "Strip VMS revisions" to 1 in FileZilla.xml to enable